# partials inside a view undefined method errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am adding partials to a show view, but I am getting errors of undefined methods that are inside the partials that are being called. I use the partials in other places and it works fine. I think I need to define a local variable, but I am not sure which one

user/show.html.erb

```
<h2>Copy To Approve</h2>
<div id="basic_details" class="idea-show-columns">
<%= render :partial => "/ideas/idea_basic_show" %>
<%= render :partial => "/ideas/comments" %>
<%= render :partial => "/ideas/mockups"%>
</div>

<div id="copy_details" class="idea-show-columns">
  <%= render :partial => "/ideas/copy_show" %>
</div>
```

partial: ideas/idea_basic_show.html.erb

```
<fieldset data-model="idea-basic" class="idea-edit">
   <h2>Basic Idea Specs</h2>

  <div data-attribute="product_sku" class="edit-field">
    <%= label :sku, "Product SKU" %>
    <%= f.text_field :sku %>
  </div>

  <div data-attribute="working_name" class="edit-field">
    <%= label :working_name, "Working Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :working_name %>
  </div>
  <div data-attribute="priority" class="edit-field">
    <%= f.label :priority, 'Priority Level' %>
    <%= f.select :priority, Idea::PRIORITIES.collect{ |level, label| [label, level]} %>
  </div>

<% if current_user.has_overlord_access? %>
      <div data-attribute="overlord_id" class="edit-field">
        <%= f.label :overlord_id, 'Sign Off' %>
        <%= f.select :overlord_id, User.overlords.collect{|o| [o.full_name, o.id]}, 
:include_blank => true %>
     </div>
 <% end %>
 <br data-clear="all" />
 <div data-attribute="working_description" class="edit-field">
   <%= label :working_description, "Working Description" %>
   <%= f.text_area :working_description %>

  </div>
    </fieldset>
```

the errors I am getting in this partial specifically is :

undefined method `sku' for nil:NilClass

Like I said I think I need to define a local in my partial I just don't know the syntax

Comment: Where does your form start? Assuming you're using `form_for` outside this partial you'll need to pass in `f` as a local

Answer (score 0):

The locals syntax like this

```
<%= render :partial => "/ideas/copy_show", :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

now use f in your partial page